# Windows Live Messenger Error

Tags: windows-live-messenger

I'm getting this error, when I'm trying to video call using Windows Live Messenger:

> Mohammad is using a version of Messenger that does not have improvements to support a Video Call. Please ask your contact to upgrade to the latest version of Messenger and try your call again.

I tried to update it but it says that there's no update available. Any ideas?

Comment: **You** don't need to update, your contact Mohammad needs to.

Comment: I'm Mohammad. This is the error message that the other person is getting.